# Stack snippets are parsed within code blocks

Tags: bug, design, stack-snippets

Today I stumbled across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43305217/1), where the placement of the stack snippet buttons irritated me.

Long story short, the `begin snippet` and `end snippet` comments seem to get parsed everywhere.

This markup:

```
Hurr

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-html -->

Durr

<!-- end snippet -->

Gurr
```

Produces this result:

```
Hurr



Durr




Gurr
```

I seems to me that this should not be so. Also, this makes it pretty hard for someone to post the source for a stack snippet in a code block.

The preview also goes completely haywire on such markup.

Fun fact: Clicking on <kbd>Expand snippet</kbd> followed by <kbd>Return to post</kbd> makes the `Gurr` part move up to between `Hurr` and `Durr`.